# "SPDX license identifier not provided" warning - what does it mean?

Tags: solidity

> Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.

Answer (score 5):

It's a warning, not an error. So you are able to compile the contract without the license identifier, and it has no effect on it's functionality.

The license identifier is one-line comment in a predefined format that states how can others use (or not use) your source code. List of allowed values linked to the open-source license types: https://spdx.org/licenses/

Examples:

- `// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT` states that others can use your source code with respect to the MIT open-source license
- `// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED` states that your code is not open-source

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    // your code
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/layout-of-source-files.html#spdx-license-identifier